# Icons Doesn't Show Up on Jekyll - Github Pages

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

here is an example of the problem: https://isengrimfaoiltiarna.github.io/cay-kahve/2018/05/17/CSharp/

Icons of share buttons doesn't show up on gh-pages. Here is what I did step by step:

1. Download icons from icomoon.io
2. Copy /fonts folder and style.css to my_jekyll_blog/css/ directory
3. Add style.css to head section.

The things is they work fine on localhost.

Edit: Silly me, I'm such a newb on web_development stuff. I just figured out there is not "icon.woff" file in github repo then checked .gitignore file (which i was copied from some tutorial). At the end I was ignoring the icon file in push. No problem at all, this question can be closed.

Comment: You forgot to copy icomoon fonts files in your fonts folder.

Comment: @DavidJacquel No, I didn't and it works on localhost. Why it works on local host?

Comment: Because you forgot to remove your font files from .gitignore. And, as I can see on your github, [you've resolved the problem](https://github.com/isengrimfaoiltiarna/isengrimfaoiltiarna.github.io/commit/d5a17a2c3e936ec211d9ae8f131f114ad7048983#diff-a084b794bc0759e7a6b77810e01874f2).

Answer (score 0):

where is put your `icons fonts folder`? it is in css folder or parallel to css folder?